# what does <![CDATA[<![CDATA[some text]]]]><![CDATA[>]]> in XML mean?

Tags: xml, cdata

I am new to XML and its related technologies.

This CDATA tag always comes at the beginning, and then followed by some stuff

I have use this in my XML file:

```
<text><![CDATA[<![CDATA[TAX INVOICE]]]]><![CDATA[>]]></text>
```

I have following question. Please help me.

what does
 `<![CDATA[some text]]]]>`
 means?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @RGraham thanks buddy for pointing me to right solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless there are special characters such as "`&`" and "`<`" in the content, the string

```
<![CDATA[xxxxx]]>
```

means exactly the same as

```
xxxxx
```

The difference is that in the second form, "`&`" and "`<`" have a special meaning, while in the CDATA form, the only thing with a special meaning is the string "`]]>`" which acts as a terminator.

Your more complex example:

```
<![CDATA[<![CDATA[TAX INVOICE]]]]><![CDATA[>]]>
```

is a bit of a nightmare, and results from a sloppy programming habit of wrapping text in CDATA sections out of laziness. CDATA sections cannot be nested, so the first `]]>` terminates the first `<!CDATA[`, which means that the string is equivalent to

```
<![CDATA[TAX INVOICE]]>
```

You might think that this in turn is equivalent to

```
TAX INVOICE
```

but that is not the case, because an XML parser will only interpret the outer CDATA delimiters, and the content it will pass to the application is therefore

```
<![CDATA[TAX INVOICE]]>
```

Answer (score 5):

The term `CDATA` comes from the `SGML` world, which is the complex predecessor of `XML`. The term is short for `Character Data` and means that the data contains of characters, and should not be parsed. Tags, entities, attributes, processing instructions inside `CDATA` are treated as text, not as `XML` elements.